# Facebook Session Destroyed after application closed

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated Facebook with my android application. it is working good but when I close the application the session is destroyed and I have to login again .

I want to remain logged-in till the user clicks on logout button? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this solution and the cause of the problem is likely found in the access token used. My guess is that you are currently using a short access token.

If you would use a long term access token, see, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/, and store it in a persistant manner the problem would be solved. Since you are using Android I would store it in SQLite and retrive upon application startup/resume.

From Facebook developer site:

> Expiration and Extending Tokens
>
> Some access tokens have a finite validity period of about one to two hours. In order to continue using these tokens after the expiry time, they need to be extended.
>
> Apps using the Facebook SDKs for Android and iOS, desktop apps or apps using the server-side login flow automatically generate long-lived user access tokens. This long-lived token refreshes and extends each time the login flow is triggered. However, apps that implement their own client-side flow must implement some server side code to manually extend the tokens using a Graph API endpoint:

So if I were you, I would try to generate a long term access token of a relevant kind, store it an a persistant way (for example in a data base) and use it upon application start or resume.

Regards,
Jonas

Answer (score 2):

As @[Jonas karlsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393767/jonas-karlsson) said i want to add some point to it.

- If you want, that the app should not ask for log-in again and again, When the app started you should use Persistent storage for that. Save the `accessToken` to a [SharedPreference storage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Because it's not a good idea to save it in a database. If your application doesn't need to use a database then it has no reason to create a database just to store one value. Use that saved access token to verify the session and it will work for you.

May this will help you... cheers...